# Cannot get RECON3D Fatal1ty Card to be recognized by the system

Tags: windows-7, audio

I just bought a Recon3D Fatal1ty sound card (Pro) by creative for my computer.  I have removed onboard sound and disabled the sound chip in my video card. From what I have read, once you plug it in to the PCI-E slot, everything should be smooth sailing.

I plug it in to any of my PCI-E slots, it lights up and that's pretty much it. Device manager doesn't see it and that renders the drivers useless as they search for the device to be installed first. Whether I use the provided CD or the website drivers, they both unpack an executable that looks for the device to be installed and then aborts install when no supported product is found.

I'm close to taking it back to where I bought it since I have not been able to find help on this topic.

I'm running an MSI motherboard model MS-7376 with Windows 7 ultimate 64-bit and 8GB ram. Video is ATI radeon HD 5670, as noted above, I have disabled onboard sound via BIOS and disabled Radeon sound via web instructions.

System currently just shows no sound at all with the card plugged in and lit up.

Any suggestions?